# Is it possible to run an external .class file using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to create a new Process that runs another class file I wrote, with specific VM arguments.
I am trying to run a class file called "Main2.class" (which has a main method) from my Bin directory, but I'm getting

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/Dean_Leitersdorf/Documents/workspace/project/bin/packageA/Main2.class": error=13, Permission denied
```

The code I have:

```
File f = new File("/Users/Dean_Leitersdorf/Documents/workspace/project/bin/packageA");
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{f.getAbsolutePath() + "/Main2.class","-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000"});

Process process = builder.start();
```

Is this even possible? If so, I would greatly appreciate any help to make it work!

Thank you,

Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run it, but you must invoke it with java.exe, just as you'd do on the command line.

Comment: Ok! Would it be: ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"java.exe",f.getAbsolutePath() + "Main2.class","-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000"});

Comment: Getting error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java.exe": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: @user3243080: Is java.exe on your system path?

Comment: How do I check that? -- I am on a Mac (I know how to on Windows..)

Comment: You need to set up the ProcessBuilder environment, just as bash does for your command line via ~/.bash_profile, etc. This includes, for example, initialising the $PATH environment variable. Alternatively, you could just use /usr/bin/java on a Mac.